# Handlebars data appearing outside of placeholders

Tags: ember.js

(This is a double-post of my identical question on the EmberJS Discuss forums.)

When a handlebars template {{value}} is somewhere where the browser doesn't reasonably expect plain text, such as a <table>, it seems to behave in unexpected ways. I've created an example page with source and included it below. Can anybody explain what is going on or why this happening, and whether or not this behavior is intentional?

*To clarify, I'm not looking for a quick way around this.  I know how to do that (as you can see from the first text in the example)  I'm curious whether anyone knows whether this behaviour is intentional or not - and why.*

Example link: http://tinyurl.com/handlebarsplaceholders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that a table element should contain content in 'tr', 'th', and 'td' tags, my assumption is that Ember is not able to properly manipulate the DOM.  Try adding a row and column and dropping your value in.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I know that works correctly, I'm just curious why the former doesn't.  When looking at the generated HTML, the second text is actually placed before the table element even begins; even though the handlebars placeholder element is correctly placed inside the table.

Comment: Looks like an issue somewhere buried in the parser.  After some romping around it's unclear where exactly it's dropping the pointer to the original object, and why it's getting rendered out of place. My guess is something returned in the lookup of that object by id coupled with the table tags is causing the browser to choke on it. I'm sure with some sifting it will become apparent..  Interesting behavior.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  Nobody else seems to know the exact details, so I'm marking this as answered.  If nothing else, it will help others who stumble upon the issue to work around it.